# pass parameters to botframework when chat session starts

Tags: botframework

I cannt find a way to pass parameters to bot framework when a session begins.
I want to pass a projectId when user starts a chat and it must be passed automatically (ie the user must not be prompted for this information).

I'm trying in vain dozens of approaches since a few days and nothing works.
I have 2 approaches that are closed to the result:

```html
var projectId ="191";
var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token });
      
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
  {},
  function() {
  return function(next) {
  return function(action) {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
  action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
  action,
  ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData'],
  () => ({
     'email': "testemail1@test.com",
     'projectId': projectId
     })
     )
      }
   return next(action);
  }
 }
);

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: d1,
    store: store,
    styleOptions:styleOptions
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));  
      

var user = {
    id: 'default-user',
    name: 'user name'
};
      
var activity = {
    from: user,
    name: 'startConversation',
    type: 'event',
    value: '',  
    channelData: {  "email": "test2@b.com","usertoken": userToken,"projectId":projectId}  
    };

    d1.postActivity(activity).subscribe(function(id) {
    if (console) {
     console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
    }
});
```

1. If i try to pass parameters through the store and DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY, the parameter are passed after the session created (too late for my need)
   2.If I passe through the postActivity of type event, I manage to override the OnEventAsynxc and access the parameters. But then I don't understand how to pass them to the dialogs.
   In the dialogs, when I dump the channelData and conversationstate or userstate, it's empty.

Please help, my need is simply to automatically pass a projectID when a chat is initiated.
Looks trivial but it is not.

```
    protected override async Task OnEventAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IStatePropertyAccessor<OnboardingState> accessor = UserState.CreateProperty<OnboardingState>(nameof(OnboardingState));
        OnboardingState state = await accessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new OnboardingState());
        state.Ticket = new CIWTicket();
        state.Ticket.SourceEmailAddress = email;
        await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `dispatch()` to send an event with the data stored in the payload. `dispatch()` is called and the event sent when direct line finalizes its connection to the bot ("CONNECTION_FULFILLED"), as demonstrated below.

```js
<script>
  (async function () {
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        console.log('Event dispatched');
        dispatch( {
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'SEND_PROJECT_ID',
            value: 191
          }
        } )
      }

      return next(action);
    });

    [...]

    window.ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactWebChat
      directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }) }
      store={store}
      />,
    document.getElementById( 'webchat' );
    )
  })
</script>
```

**Developer's console**

[image]

**Logged by bot**

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: let me test this. Do I get access to the data in the first waterfallstep of MainDialog?

Comment: No, because it occurs on "CONNECT_FULFILLED", your bot receives the data before the waterfall is started or any welcome message is sent. Rather, on your mainBot.cs file, filter using the "onEvent" activity handler. You can save it to state and make it accessible to your bot once the dialog begins.

Comment: How do I do that? I have a DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs file where I have overwritten OnEventAsync (same file that contains OnMembersAddedAsync). See OnEventAsync code in my initial post. But I do not get the data in the MainDialog.

Comment: Referencing the [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Bots/DialogBot.cs) sample, the ActivityHandlers are located in the "DialogBot.cs" file. The 
`onTurnAsync()` and `onMessageActivityAsync()` methods are accessed via the `ActivityHandler` class at the top. You can monitor incoming activities in one of those. Obviously, the "message" handler only passes thru messages. The "turn" handler will show everything. There are other handlers you can use, as well.